# How i can publish a openshift app in tk domain?

Tags: openshift, appdomain, tk-toolkit

I am trying to register an app in Openshift, in tk domain using freenom. However, when I go to "URL Forwarding" and put the url of the app "xxxx-xxx.rhcloud.com" I have the following error:

`Given URL returns 500`

I see that the app is running.

Any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finnally I find that openshift can't use url forwadding.

The only option is use cname way. (In dot tk select default name servers and later click over "Manage Freenom DNS"

Previously you need create alias in openshift, this opperation can be done in the app console web interface, create alias option is near app web direction.

here a link with more information:

https://blog.openshift.com/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way/